# Find specific tags in a HTML file

Tags: html, regex, linux, bash

I have some html files and want to extract the contents between some tags:
The title of the page
some tagged content here.

```
<p>A paragraph comes here</p>
<p>A paragraph comes here</p><span class="more-about">Some text here</span><p class="en-cpy">Copyright &copy; 2012 </p>
```

I just want these tags: head, p
but as could be seen in the second paragraph, the last tag is  which starts with p but is not my desires tag, and I don't want its content.
I used following script for extracting my desired text, but I can't filter out the tags such as the last one in my example.... How is it possible to extract just `<p>` tags?

```
grep "<p>" $File | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

I have to add that, the last tag (which I don't want to appear in the output) is right after  one of my desired tags (as is in my example) and using grep command all the content of that line would be returned as output... (This is my problem)

Answer (score 3):

Don't. Trying to use `regex` to parse **HTML** is going to be [painful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/56763). Use something like `Ruby` and `Nokogiri`, or a similar language + library that you are familiar with.

Comment: XSLT is a general-purpose tool  (and language) for this. Google for `xsltproc` examples.

Comment: If you have valid XHTML (i.e. valid XML), then this is definitely a easier route

Comment: Wow, XSLT seems a strange tool, but I don't have time. I have to do it  in 1 hour, and it seems that I have to spend time on learning how to create an xsl file.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmllint --html --xpath "//*[name()='head' or name()='p']" "$file"
```

If you're dealing with broken HTML you might need a different parser. Here's a "one-liner" basically the same using `lxml`. Just pass the script your URL

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from lxml import etree
import sys

print('\n'.join(etree.tostring(x, encoding="utf-8", with_tail=False).decode("utf-8") for x in (lambda i: etree.parse(i, etree.HTMLParser(remove_blank_text=1, remove_comments=1)).xpath("//*[name()='p' or name()='head']"))(sys.argv[0])))
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" tells me nothing. You need libxml of course, or you can optionally use any of the many other commandline tools that can process an xpath.

Comment: yeah, I have libxml, but it seems that this command echos all the contents of the file.

Comment: Well it should work. If you get parse errors and are dealing with broken html you might need a different parser... edited with a python example.

Answer (score 0):

to extract text between <p> and </p>, try this

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/="</p>";$\="\n"}s/.*(<p>)/$1/&&print' < input-file > output-file
```

or

```
perl -n0l012e 'print for m|<p>.*?</p>|gs'
```